I am unable to use Jaxb generated classes from xsd to send request in json format
Basically, my project is soap web service using spring boot. where I was provided with wsdl/xsd files, from which pojo classes have been created using jaxb. As a normal process my project is absolutely working fine for xml requests. but now I want to reuse same project for rest calls for front end applications. I created a controller but when I send request in json format, objects which are @XmlType are always null. any suggestions, on how to reuse same jaxb created classes for json requests.
I tried to create new pojos but it wont work as it calls service layer.

What do you mean by @XmlType ? I already used generated java class by maven-jaxb2-plugin in both XML and JSON exchange without any problem so I'd need more details for me to help you. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
